# Why do I have to remove/rescan my PCIe devices for the Kernel to allocate it's BAR memory?

Tags: linux, memory, drivers, pci-express

When I cold-boot my SuperMicro server, the kernel dmesg log states that it **finds my PCIe cards and their required MEM spaces for their BARs**...

```
[  +0.000036] pci 0000:19:00.0: [10de:1eb1] type 00 class 0x030000
[  +0.000022] pci 0000:19:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc3000000-0xc3ffffff]
[  +0.000011] pci 0000:19:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0x3807e0000000-0x3807efffffff 64bit pref]
[  +0.000010] pci 0000:19:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0x3807f0000000-0x3807f1ffffff 64bit pref]
[  +0.000006] pci 0000:19:00.0: reg 0x24: [io  0x7000-0x707f]
[  +0.000006] pci 0000:19:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xc4000000-0xc407ffff pref]
[  +0.000006] pci 0000:19:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[  +0.000149] pci 0000:19:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[  +0.000075] pci 0000:19:00.1: [10de:10f8] type 00 class 0x040300
[  +0.000018] pci 0000:19:00.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc4080000-0xc4083fff]
[  +0.000048] pci 0000:19:00.1: enabling Extended Tags
[  +0.000169] pci 0000:19:00.2: [10de:1ad8] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[  +0.000022] pci 0000:19:00.2: reg 0x10: [mem 0x3807f2000000-0x3807f203ffff 64bit pref]
[  +0.000019] pci 0000:19:00.2: reg 0x1c: [mem 0x3807f2040000-0x3807f204ffff 64bit pref]
[  +0.000020] pci 0000:19:00.2: enabling Extended Tags
[  +0.000134] pci 0000:19:00.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[  +0.000041] pci 0000:19:00.3: [10de:1ad9] type 00 class 0x0c8000
[  +0.000018] pci 0000:19:00.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc4084000-0xc4084fff]
[  +0.000047] pci 0000:19:00.3: enabling Extended Tags
[  +0.000134] pci 0000:19:00.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
```

and for the second device:

```
[  +0.000073] pci 0000:1a:00.0: [10ee:d03c] type 00 class 0x120000
[  +0.000020] pci 0000:1a:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xc0000000-0xc1ffffff]
[  +0.000008] pci 0000:1a:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xc2000000-0xc200ffff]
[  +0.000043] pci 0000:1a:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
```

**Then later the log says that it failed to allocated MEM space for multiple PCIe cards in the system:**

```
[  +0.000134] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 3: assigned [mem 0x380410000000-0x380411ffffff 64bit pref]
[  +0.000135] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x01000000]
[  +0.000093] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x01000000]
[  +0.000096] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 6: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
[  +0.000095] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
[  +0.000124] pci 0000:19:00.2: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x380412000000-0x38041203ffff 64bit pref]
[  +0.000135] pci 0000:19:00.2: BAR 3: assigned [mem 0x380412040000-0x38041204ffff 64bit pref]
[  +0.000134] pci 0000:19:00.1: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00004000]
[  +0.000093] pci 0000:19:00.1: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000]
[  +0.000096] pci 0000:19:00.3: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00001000]
[  +0.000094] pci 0000:19:00.3: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00001000]
[  +0.000096] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 5: assigned [io  0x4000-0x407f]
[  +0.000108] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x01000000]
[  +0.000094] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x01000000]
[  +0.000096] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 6: no space for [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
[  +0.000095] pci 0000:19:00.0: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
[  +0.000124] pci 0000:19:00.1: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00004000]
[  +0.000094] pci 0000:19:00.1: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00004000]
[  +0.000095] pci 0000:19:00.3: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x00001000]
[  +0.000094] pci 0000:19:00.3: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x00001000]
```

and the second device:

```
[  +0.000131] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x02000000]
[  +0.000094] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x02000000]
[  +0.000095] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00010000]
[  +0.000094] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00010000]
[  +0.000095] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x02000000]
[  +0.000094] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x02000000]
[  +0.000095] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00010000]
[  +0.000093] pci 0000:1a:00.0: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00010000]
```

**See the missing addresses for one of the devices**

```
$ sudo lspci -vd 10ee:
1a:00.0 Processing accelerators: Xilinx Corporation Device d03c (rev 02)
Subsystem: Xilinx Corporation Device 000e
Physical Slot: 9
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26, NUMA node 0
Memory at <ignored> (32-bit, non-prefetchable)
Memory at <ignored> (32-bit, non-prefetchable)
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [1c0] #19
Kernel driver in use: xclmgmt
Kernel modules: xclmgmt
```

Now, I can simply remove the root port, as many questions/answers on the site point me to do, and then rescan under

```
$ echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:ROOTPORT:0.0/remove 
$ echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan


$ sudo lspci -vd 10ee:
1a:00.0 Processing accelerators: Xilinx Corporation Device d03c (rev 02)
Subsystem: Xilinx Corporation Device 000e
Physical Slot: 9
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33, NUMA node 0
Memory at ac000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
Memory at ab000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [1c0] #19
Kernel driver in use: xclmgmt
Kernel modules: xclmgmt
```

***These steps work every time.***

I don't know why this is required...

The two cards are from two different vendors (NVIDIA, Xilinx), with different drivers. Is there a configuration in Ubuntu that I can do to force this every time? Is the BIOS not passing the enumeration data correctly?